# Kibana Timestamp diffrent between Date seen in browser and JSON

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I stored an index that contains fields as timestamp.
When I consult the data in Kibana it's OK and the timestamp is equal to what I stored :

```
expirationDate : Dec 1, 2027 @ 00:00:00.000
```

[image: Kibana result]

But in ELK request the result is not the same :

```
"expirationDate": "2027-11-30T23:00:00.000Z"
```

For information, Kibana date is the correct one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Kibana shows you the dates in your [browser timezone by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.8/advanced-options.html#kibana-general-settings). You can go to Advanced Settings and change the `dateFormat:tz` setting if you wish to change the way your dates are displayed.

If you want to save the date in your timezone, you can do so, but it's not considered good practice.

```
"expirationDate": "2027-12-01T00:00:00.000+01:00"
```

Comment: But Kibana date is the correct one. Why ELK send the date minus 1 hour ?

Comment: It's not minus one hour, it's the date and time in the Zulu `Z` timezone, i.e. Greenwich time. You're probably located on UTC+1, so when it's midnight where you are, it's 23:00 the day before in the Z timezone

Comment: Thanks for explication. There is no way to tell ELK to save date as it ?